# Run a python script on a remote machine without sudo previlage

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, freeze, remote-server

I have a python script called ergo.py on my local machine and I want to run it on a remote machine but I have a couple of issues:

1. The remote machine has python 2.x installed on it but my code is written in python 3.x
2. The remote machine doesn't have python modules like numpy or matplotlib.
3. I only have ssh access to remote machine and I don't have sudo privilege or any root access
4. I even don't have sudo privilege or any root access on my local machine but I have python 3.6.3 and anaconda packages installed on it which make me able to write my codes with Pycharm IDE.

The remote machine and my local system both have Linux Red hat 7.x operating systems.

What is my best way to run my codes on the remote machine. I tried to freeze my code using pyinstaller, bbfreeze and cx_freeze but I didn't succeed, each time becasue of a specific error so I quitted this option.

Comment: You may try to install all required modules in your HOME directory, without need of `root`. Use `pip install -u <module...>` on a remote host for that.

Certainly if your script needs modules with native code, the target computer may need a C compiler with all required libs. You may manually upload pre-built modules and/or shared libraries to ~/.local/lib/python2.7/... etc.

Also you may need to port your script back to python2, because installing a whole python distribution in your home directory on a remote host can be a difficult task, depending on disk space and other resources limits

Comment: @user3159253 Thank you for your reply. I think that this solution works for the modules, however I want a way which does not require me to change my code from python3 to python 2. I think I don't have considerable resource limitation on the host but what I mentioned above.

Comment: I had this same problem and I installed Anaconda in my home directory. You also need to add the new install to your path. Don’t forget about configuring .profile as ssh ssh doesn’t load .bashrc automatically.

Comment: @Boergler Thank you. Yes, exactly anaconda is the best solution I just found an instruction and posted it

Comment: By the way, you can run jupyter notebook from the server like this: jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=9889  or using any port you like. Then use a SSH tunnel (in putty perhaps) to map port 9889 to localhost:9889. Putting http://localhost:9889/tree into your local browser will load the remote jupyter notebook server.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very good solution on this website https://research.computing.yale.edu/support/hpc/user-guide/local-anaconda-installation

Just sweep the Anaconda version to the desired version in the instruction